# consecutive dice throw problem

Tags: probability

Consider a fair die with 6 faces - the probability of each number appearing on any throw is equal to 1/6.
What is the minimum number of times should a player throw the die before his/her probability of
getting two consecutive sixes is greater than 1/2?

Comment: This is accessible to (standard) recursive one-step methods allowing to compute the generating functions of the first time to get 66, the first time to get 6 and the first time to get 66 once one got 6. Did you try this route and, if you did, what is blocking you? More generally: explain what you did.

Answer (score 1):

using bernoilles trials , if an event is repeated $n$ times and if probability  of success is $p$ and $q$ the probability of failure . then the event happening $r$ times in $n$ trials is
$$P(r) = ^{n}C_{r}p^{r}q^{n-r}$$
here $r =2$.
as you are requiring consecutive terms $p= \frac {1}{6}*\frac{1}{6} =\frac{1}{36}$ and $q =\frac{35}{36}$. find $n$

Comment: The trials in this case are not independent since the result depends on two throws.

Comment: Keyword: "consecutive".

Comment: this case is independent of independency

Comment: You are considering the probability to get exactly two successes at any time during the n first trials. The OP is concerned with the probability to get at least two **consecutive** successes at any time during the n first trials.

Comment: i have edited the answer.

Comment: Still wrong. @upvoter Why the upvote?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, but isn't a full solution.

Let $a_n$ be the number of sequences of n throws which do not contain two consecutive $6$s and in which the last throw is not a 6, and $b_n$ be the number of sequences without a double six in which the last throw is a $6$.

A sequence of $n+1$ throws without a double six in which the last throw is a $6$ is obtained by having the first $n$ throws not end in a six, and then throwing a six - thus $$b_{n+1}=a_n$$

A sequence of $n+1$ throws without a double six and which don't end in a six can be obtained from any sequence of length $n$ without a double six by throwing $1,2,3,4,5$ hence$$a_{n+1}=5(a_n+b_n)$$

Substituting $b_n=a_{n-1}$ we obtain $$a_{n+1}=5a_n+5a_{n-1}$$

Solving the recurrence gives $a_n$ and hence $b_n$, from which $a_n+b_n$ can be determined.

The number of sequences of length $n$ is $6^n$.